# Json File - Changed Tracking and Reload

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console application which has a AppConfiguration file which provides different app-settings. I have added in the main-method the creation of a `ConfigurationBuilder` object and added the `reloadOnChange` flag for that JSON file like in the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Program started...");
    Console.WriteLine("Stop Program by Ctrl+C");

    //Add Exit Possibility
    Console.CancelKeyPress += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

    //Add Configuration Builder
    Console.Write("Load Shared Configuration...");
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("SharedAppConfiguration.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
    Console.WriteLine("done");

}
```

How can I catch or get information about the event, that the JSON file "SharedAppConfiguration.json" has changed?

I've tried to do something like this:

```
Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration").Bind(appConfiguration);
```

But like it looks, there is no `.Bind` method in .NET Core console application - in ASP.NET it’s available.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the [`Bind` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=aspnetcore-2.0) on the configuration objects, you also need the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder). `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` only comes with the base stuff to work with the configuration, and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` is only the loader for JSON files.

To answer your other question, about how to get notified about configuration changes for JSON configuration files with `reloadOnChange: true`, you can use the reload change token for this. It’s easiest to use the [`ChangeToken.OnChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.changetoken.onchange?view=aspnetcore-2.0) helper function for that:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("file.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

// register change callback
ChangeToken.OnChange(() => configuration.GetReloadToken(), () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Configuration changed");
});
```

If you are using the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1), you can also use the [options monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for this.

Comment: is there a way we can check what property and which file has been changed instead of having a generic "Configuration Changed" message?

Comment: @DotNetDev The interface does not offer this, no. The configuration is also supposed to be source-agnostic, so it does not matter where a configuration value comes from (and you cannot tell from outside where it came from). Similarly, providing a diff per configuration path would be something very expensive to do that does not really give you benefits for configurations: You should just consume the configuration as is; changes should only trigger a reload of whatever depends on the configuration. – If you need more control, then Configuration is probably not the solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks @poke for mentioning options monitor, this is what I needed!