# Detect changes using ChangeToken.OnChange()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How to check what configuration file/ setting has been changed?

I have configured the `ChangeToken.OnChange()` method to detect changes to configuration files

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("settings1.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile("settings2.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);  
    .Build();


// register change callback
ChangeToken.OnChange(
    () => configuration.GetReloadToken(),
    () => {
        logger.Info("Configuration file has been changed"); //want to know specifically what has changed
    }
);
```

This detects any changes to the settings1.json and settings2.json, but I want to know which file has been changed and what property has changed?

Comment: As [mentioned in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292700/json-file-changed-tracking-and-reload/52301961?noredirect=1#comment98945374_52301961), you won’t be able to get this information from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. – I would suggest you to actually ask about the *real problem* you are trying to solve here since this appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141542) to me where Configuration isn’t the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Microsoft suggests a trick to do it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-6.0 (this is valid not only for .NET6)

Answer (score -2):

I think configuration revision history not saved while calling `onChange()` method.

If you want to track your config history, you could use version control such as [Git](https://desktop.github.com/) or SVN.

On every change, you could commit it.

[image]