# configuration Reinitialize Singleton asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a singleton class BotSettings that reads configuration values from the appsettings.json file. I recently came across an article that explains how to modify the appsettings.json file at runtime using the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration library (Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/299791/saving-to-appsettings-json). It works fine, and the changes are reflected when I read the configuration again.

However, my challenge is that I need to reinitialize the instance of the BotSettings singleton class after modifying the appsettings.json file, so that it can pick up the updated configuration values without restarting the application.
Note ("BUT i don't want use IOptionsSnapshot , and want use IOptions")

I noticed that the BotSettings class holds the configuration values in memory and doesn't have a mechanism to reload the values after they've been changed. I've tried to create a method in the class that reloads the configuration, but I'm unsure how to trigger it automatically when the appsettings.json file changes.

Could someone please guide me on how to reinitialize the BotSettings singleton class after modifying the appsettings.json file at runtime? Is there a way to detect changes to the configuration file and automatically update the singleton instance? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a singleton. Use configuration binding and/or the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to get the current settings values as an object. You can use either IOptionsMonitor or IOptionsSnapshot to retrieve updated data. `IOptionsSnapshot` will retrieve the settings value once per scope/request, ensuring controllers and actions see stable values. `IOptionsMonitor` retrieves the current value at any time, which means the same request may encounter different settings values while it runs

Comment: `Note ("BUT i don't want use IOptionsSnapshot , and want use IOptions")` if you don't, you'll have to reinvent them. Your singleton will have to do what `IOptionsSnapshot` or `Monitor` does, read settings on *every* request, convert them to objects, possibly implement caching so it doesn't have to read everything every time. And if you want stable values per request, you'll have to implement scopes in your `BotSettings` that either return the same value inside a scope, or return a `BotSettingsScope` with that scope's values.

Comment: Don't inject the ```SettingsObject``` directly. The `Options Pattern` is amazing. Why wouldn't you want to benefit from it?

Comment: If you insist on writing your own code, you can use [IConfiguration.GetReloadToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration.getreloadtoken?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration-getreloadtoken) to get a class that will call your own callbacks when settings change. The answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292700/json-file-changed-tracking-and-reload) shows how to use the `ChangeToken.OnChange` helper for this. You may get duplicate notifications though.

Comment: I meant the same IOption<T>, not to add it as a singleton service, the reason was that I didn't want it to refer to the file and read from the file every time, because the settings are not something that can be changed too much, one way came to my mind and that is that every Every time a change occurs, I will get the new settings again using the IOptionSnapshot<T> and Get T From IOption Then Change It Based On IOptionSnapShot, but should this be done manually every time in the methods, or should it be done automatically in a part of the program every time the reload happens

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IOptionsMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#ioptionsmonitor). One way is to just subscribe to the changes and act accordingly:

```cs
var optionsMonitor = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<CustomSettings>>();
optionsMonitor.OnChange(settings =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(settings.Test); // do magic here
});
app.Run();
GC.KeepAlive(optionsMonitor);
```

But I would argue that the better just use the `IOptionsSnapshot` and skip the singleton. If that is not an option - then `BotSettings` would be better designed as a wrapper around the `IOptionsMonitor` and exposing `IOptionsMonitor<>.CurrentValue`.